# UWP Hide TabView Footer

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, tabview

I have TabView that basically looks like this:

```
    <controls:TabView
        x:Name="PlaylistTabView">
        <controls:TabView.ItemHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Playlist">
                // Something
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:TabView.ItemHeaderTemplate>
        <controls:TabView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Playlist">
                <local:HeaderedPlaylistControl IsPlaylist="True" Loaded="HeaderedPlaylistControl_Loaded" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:TabView.ItemTemplate>

        <controls:TabView.TabStartHeader>
            // Something
        </controls:TabView.TabStartHeader>

        <controls:TabView.TabEndHeader>
            // Something
        </controls:TabView.TabEndHeader>

        <controls:TabView.Footer>
            <RelativePanel
                x:Name="PlaylistFooter"
                Height="{StaticResource PlaylistTabFooterHeight}"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
                <RelativePanel.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform />
                </RelativePanel.RenderTransform>
                <local:IconTextButton
                    x:Name="ShowAllPlaylistButton"
                    Padding="10,5"
                    IconTextMargin="0,0,10,0"
                    LabelPosition="Left"
                    RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                    Style="{StaticResource PlaylistIconTextButtonStyle}"
                    ToolTipService.ToolTip="Show All Playlists">
                    <local:IconTextButton.Icon>
                        <FontIcon
                            x:Name="UpArrowIcon"
                            FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                            FontWeight="{x:Bind ShowAllPlaylistButton.FontWeight}"
                            Glyph="&#xE70E;"
                            RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                            <FontIcon.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform />
                            </FontIcon.RenderTransform>
                        </FontIcon>
                    </local:IconTextButton.Icon>
                    <local:IconTextButton.Flyout>
                        <MenuFlyout Closed="ClosePlaylistsFlyout" Opening="OpenPlaylistsFlyout" />
                    </local:IconTextButton.Flyout>
                </local:IconTextButton>
                <local:IconTextButton
                    x:Name="SortByButton"
                    Padding="10,5"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Icon="Sort"
                    IconTextMargin="10,0,0,0"
                    Label="Sort By Title"
                    LabelPosition="Right"
                    RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                    Style="{StaticResource PlaylistIconTextButtonStyle}"
                    Tapped="SortByButton_Tapped"
                    ToolTipService.ToolTip="Sort Playlists" />
            </RelativePanel>
        </controls:TabView.Footer>
    </controls:TabView>
```

I have a `local:HeaderedPlaylistControl` in the `ItemTemplate` which is basically a `ListView`. I want to implement the effect that as you scroll down the footer will translate down and when you scroll up the footer will quickly show up.

I am able to implement such effect. However, I am only moving the `PlaylistFooter` not the `TabView.Footer`, meaning that the `Footer` lingers and leaves a blank space at the bottom as is shown in the picture below. How can I move the footer as well?

[image: Hidden]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code， I found you have implemented `TranslateTransform` for `PlaylistFooter`, if you just move the `PlaylistFooter` down not set Visibility as `Collapsed`, the footer will still display, So the better way is set  Visibility as `Collapsed`.

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="FooterVisibilityStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="FooterFadeIn">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaylistFooter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="1" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaylistFooter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="Visibility" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="FooterFadeOut">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaylistFooter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaylistFooter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="Collapsed" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaylistFooter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

**Update**

After discuss with Seaky Luo, we found a solution that set `PlaylistFooter` height as 0 when the list view scroll down. For more please refer the following code.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="HideFooterAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="PlaylistFooter"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)"
            To="0"
            Duration="0:0:0.1" />
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            Storyboard.TargetName="PlaylistFooter"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
            Duration="0:0:0.1">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PlaylistTabFooterHeight}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="ShowFooterAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="PlaylistFooter"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)"
            To="{StaticResource PlaylistTabFooterHeight}"
            Duration="0" />
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            Storyboard.TargetName="PlaylistFooter"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
            Duration="0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: I am not looking for the FadeIn/Out effects but element translations. I want the footer and its content to move downward at the same time.

Comment: Yep, the better way is custom TabView and add the above VisualState for the [footer](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/TabView/TabView.xaml#L230), then invoke the two visualstates, when your listview scroll up and down. it's hard to design

Comment: If you want me to customize it, where can I find the source style of `TabView`? I think it might be easier to set the `TabView.Footer` background to transparent.

Comment: And you could also add the translations in above code, but it will flash when the footer hide. `<DoubleAnimation
    Storyboard.TargetName="TranslateVertical"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
    From="0.5"
    To="30"
    Duration="0:0:0.4"
    />`

Comment: I have shared the TableView [style](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/TabView/TabView.xaml#L230) above.

Comment: Strange, do you know why the Footer is still white even though I set it to transparent? Changing background should work because I am able to see it become black when I set the background. My code has also been updated. It is the `PlaylistTabView.xaml` under Dictionaries folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199881/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-seaky-luo).

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this earlier.